# What is XML file needed to test for Spring Configuration Errors?

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven

I am testing my configuration file setup. I understand that I need

```
@ContextConfiguration({"/test-applicationContext.xml"})
```

and

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

I also understand that this xml file should be placed in src/test/java/resources. What I can't find is a clear explanation of what exactly goes into this xml file to make the test run. I would just like to run my test which loads my base level config file which is written in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml. My base level config file import several other config files. I want to make sure everything is wired up correctly.

Can someone please tell me what goes in the test-applicationContext.xml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily **need** a `test-applicationContext.xml` file; you would typically only have a file like that if you needed to use an alternate bean for testing (one that did not hit a production system, for instance). You should just need to point `@ContextConfiguration` to your main application context file(s) and all should be well.

Comment: where would I find the main application context file?

Comment: Not sure I can answer that question. If it's your app, and you don't know, it sounds like you don't have one. Which would make one wonder why you are trying to use the above annotations at all. Are you sure you are using Spring? If so, are you using JavaConfig instead of XML to wire things together? If so, you probably want something like this: `@ContextConfiguration(classes={MyConfig1.class, MyConfig2.class})`

Comment: It's not my app...it's an app that I'm working on...a large project and I'm the new kid on the block.

Comment: There could be no application context XML files, in which case there would be JavaConfig classes that do the wiring. Or, there could be one, or more, application context XML files. If there are XML files, some semi-standard locations are `src/main/resources`, `src/main/resources/META-INF`, or under `src/main/java/...` along-side the source files. I don't think I can help much more.

Comment: @KPrince36 that's like asking from us where your class file is. We cannot know that. However, since you have src/main/webapp/WEB-INF folder, my first guess would be src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring.